# Inserting div into existing div with class only

Tags: javascript, appendchild

I'm trying to create a new div in Javascript with two spans in it, each containing a string of text. They are then meant to be inserted before div.two in div.inner.

The div I'm trying to insert it into only has a class and I cannot target it by any ID, unfortunately.

I have also created a codepen here: https://codepen.io/lisaschumann/pen/BXqJKY

Any help is massively appreciated!

**HTML**

```
<html>
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
  </div>
</html>
```

**JS**

```
window.onload=function(){
  var infobox = document.createElement("div");
  infobox.classList.add('infobox');

  var spanOne = document.createElement("div");
  var spanOneText = document.createTextNode('Important text 1');

  var spanTwo = document.createElement("div");
  var spanTwoText = document.createTextNode('Important text 2');

  spanOne.appendChild(spanOneText);
  spanTwo.appendChild(spanTwoText);
  infobox.appendChild(spanOne);
  infobox.appendChild(spanTwo);

  var targetDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("inner");
  targetDiv.insertBefore(infobox, targetDiv.childNodes[1]);
}
```

**Errors:**

> Cannot read property '1' of undefined
>      at window.onload

Comment: Why not debug your code, step through it and see, which method calls actually return null?

Comment: `document.getElementsByClassName("inner")` will return a HTMLCollection, not a single element. Try using `document.getElementsByClassName("inner")[0]` or `document.querySelector("inner")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a live collection of nodes rather than one node and so you would need to access the correct node in that list similar to an array: `targetDiv[0]`, perhaps.

The easier method is to use [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to grab the element you want using its class, for example:

```
var parent = document.querySelector(".inner");
var two = document.querySelector(".two");
parent.insertBefore(infobox, two);
```

But! there's even a shortcut method you can use here that allows you to add an HTML string direct to the DOM which might save you a bit of time, and some code.

```js
// Create the HTML
const html = `
  <div>
    <span>Text alpha</span>
    <span>Text beta</span>
  </div>`;

// Grab the element containing your "two" class
const two = document.querySelector('.inner .two');

// Using insertAdjacentHTML to add the HTML before the two element
two.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', html);
```

```html
<div class="inner">Inner
  <div class="one">one</div>
  <div class="two">two</div>
</div>
```

- [insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

Comment: Thank you so much! This has worked perfectly! Thank you also for the detailed explanation.

Comment: @Lisa if this answered your question, don't forget to mark it as the correct answer by clicking the tickmark next to Andy's answer.

Comment: @DanPantry oh gotcha! thanks for pointing that out - I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't work because of these lines

```
var targetDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("inner");
targetDiv.insertBefore(infobox, targetDiv.childNodes[1]);
```

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a `NodeList`. `targetDiv.childNodes` is `undefined`, because `childNodes` doesn't exist on a `NodeList`.

You need to either use a list operation like `Array.prototype.forEach`, change `getElementsByClassName` to `getElementByClassName` (note the `s`) or access the first node in the node list using the array indexer syntax.

I assume you meant to do something like this:

```
var targetDiv = document.getElementByClassName('inner')
targetDiv.insertBefore(infobox, targetDiv.childNodes[1])
```

This will insert a node in between the first and second child of the first DOM node with the class `inner`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out , targetDiv is an array by default due to the getElementsByClassName method , even though it has a single element.Hence you need to specify the index i.e. 0 ( as it's the first element of the array)

`var targetDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("inner")[0]; targetDiv.insertBefore(infobox, targetDiv.children[1]); }`

Answer (score -2):

Using JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(`<div>Important text 1<span></span>Important text 2<span></span></div>`).insertBefore( ".inner .two" );
)
```

I would encourage you to use JQuery and then shift to vanilla javascript later on. You can do simple tasks like this in just few lines of code and it is also easily debuggable because of that

Comment: This is not good advice and, while it does solve the users problem, it does it without teaching the user what the problem is. A good answer will explain the issue with the users code and propose a solution. "just use jQuery" is not a good solution.

Comment: @DanPantry Ik but for starters I think we should use JQuery. The rest is upto her

Comment: It is even more dangerous to suggest a tool to a beginner (I assume that's what you mean "for starters") because then you run the risk of them not understanding the problem *or* proposed solution. It's perfectly fine to suggest jQuery here, but you should expand on your answer to explain what the actual problem is and how it can be resolved - with jQuery being one of those potential solutions.